# php form echo not working

Tags: php, forms

I'm running a select statement to retrieve db values. I then and display / echo the retrieved data into the form fields.

The 'author' data displays correctly in the author field

The 'keywords' data displays correctly

However the data from the 'content' variable isn't displaying the in the form textarea.
I'm aware the value = is missing from the statement, but this does not make a difference

I have used echo to confirm that the $content variable contains the required data

Am I missing something obvious? Any help greatly appreciated :)

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['edit_post'])) { 
  $edit_id = $_GET['edit_post'];

  $select_post = "select * FROM posts WHERE post_id = '$edit_id'";  
  run_query = mysql_query($select_post);
  while($row_posts = mysql_fetch_array($run_query)) {

  $author = $row_posts['post_author'];
  $keywords = $row_posts['post_keywords'];     
  $content = $row_content['post_content'];
      }
  }
 ?>




      <tr> 
        <td align="right" bgcolor="#ccc"> Author:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="post_author" value ="<?php echo $author;?>"/></td>
    </tr>   



     <tr> 
        <td align="right" bgcolor="#ccc"> Keywords:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="post_keywords" size="100" value ="<?php echo     $keywords;?>"/></td>
    </tr>   



    <tr> 
        <td align="right" bgcolor="#ccc"> Content:</td>
        <td><textarea name="post_content" rows="10" cols="60"><?php echo $content;?>             </textarea></td>
    </tr>
```

many thanks,
P

Answer (score 7):

You are accessing `$content` wrongly

```
$content = $row_content['post_content'];
```

As you are storing the query result in `$row_posts` , it should be

```
$content = $row_posts['post_content'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['edit_post'])) { 
  $edit_id = $_GET['edit_post'];

  $select_post = "select * FROM posts WHERE post_id = '$edit_id'";  
  $run_query = mysql_query($select_post); 
  $author = "";
  $keywords = "";     
  $content = "";
  if(mysql_num_rows($run_query)>0) {
  $row_posts = mysql_fetch_array($run_query);
  $author = $row_posts['post_author'];
  $keywords = $row_posts['post_keywords'];     
  $content = $row_posts['post_content'];
      }
  }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one `$content = $row_posts['post_content'];`

instead of `$content = $row_content['post_content'];`